# How to check whether DST is applicable for current timezone

Tags: timezone, dst

Anyone knows how to decide in Dot Net, whether DST is applicable for the current time zone?

For example,

Brisbane time zone has no DST, where as Adelaide time zone has DST

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

Check the `TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById` function and the `TimeZoneInfo.SupportsDaylightSavingTime` property.

Please refer below link:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/fff4de50-2230-4e34-8ec4-c6afff854ea0/how-to-check-whether-dst-is-applicable-for-current-timezone?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: FYI - Link-only answers are discouraged on StackOverflow.